# Selenium WebDriver (IE Driver) cannot find element with substring for an ID

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-9

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id$='_NewSiteMaintenanceButton']"));
```

The line above works with Chrome AND FireFox, but when I try to execute it in IE I get:

> Test Outcome: Failed Result
>
> Message:  OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find
>   element with css selector == [id$='_NewSiteSearch_listbox'] Result
>   StackTrace:
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism,
>   String value)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1c(ISearchContext context)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)

What causes this, and how should I resolve it?

**EDIT:**
Explicitly calling it:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id='#3_NewSiteMaintenanceButton']"));
```

Fails too, whereas in Chrome AND FireFox that works

Comment: `$` part of attribute?

Comment: @Saifur $='_NewSiteMaintenanceButton'" is supposed to get and ID that ends with _NewSiteMaintenanceButton, so if the actual ID is 111_NewSiteMaintenanceButton, it should find it.

Comment: @Arran IE9, I cannot change the version, as that is required for our testing

Comment: @JamesMadison, alright, so take Selenium out of the equation. Open IE's developer tools, and go it's console, run the same query there: `document.querySelector('[id$='_NewSiteMaintenanceButton']')`...what do you get?

Comment: @Arran $("[id$='_NewSiteMaintenanceButton']")  returns length 1

Comment: @JamesMadison, that's jQuery and not IE's CSS Engine (usually, anyway), please double check that.

Comment: @Arran document.querySelector("[id$='_NewSiteMaintenanceButton']") returns what appears to be an HTML element, although IE sucks at displaying what you found

Comment: Can you provide the html?

Comment: How long is it taking before it bombs out? (Is it crashing out instantly or waiting?)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, find the element `By.xpath()`:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//*[ends-with(@id, '_NewSiteMaintenanceButton']"));
```